# Average of multiple rows by name or row number in R

Tags: r

A dataset in R looks like below:

```
             LD.D        LD.L            LD.P
Y.1992.a1   67.89552605 33.21192862 90.7750688
Y.1992.a2   227.1370541 79.67211036 154.5165077
Y.1992.a3   94.5326718  24.72816922 151.665545
Y.1992.a4   106.8793485 56.07635245 100.6711004
Y.1992.a5   97.41402289 46.93434073 100.8787496
Y.1993.a1   150.045093  19.64290196 27.81953228
Y.1993.a2   106.5888189 21.38886866 84.82532249
Y.1993.a3   110.7493543 25.41765759 70.02222315
Y.1993.a4   237.1246502 16.43006029 75.17407065
Y.1993.a5   234.5403261 16.93082727 49.01639754
Y.1994.a1   94.5326718  24.72816922 151.665545
Y.1994.a2   106.8793485 56.07635245 100.6711004
Y.1994.a3   97.41402289 46.93434073 100.8787496
Y.1994.a4   150.045093  19.64290196 27.81953228
Y.1994.a5   106.5888189 21.38886866 84.82532249
```

For each year I have got five replicates. The question is how could I have the aveage of each single  year (e.g., 1992 and 1993 and 1994)?

Answer (score 3):

You could do this using either `base R` or with specialized packages such as `dplyr` or `data.table` (more efficient when the dataset is really big).

```
df$Year <- gsub("^.\\.(\\d+)\\..*", "\\1", row.names(df)) #extracted the year alone from the row names and created a column `Year` in the dataset 
library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
    group_by(Year) %>% #grouped by Year variable
    summarise_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE))) #when you specify the function, `summarise_each will applies the function (here it is mean) to each of the columns in the dataset or a subset of columns (if specified) 

 #    Source: local data frame [3 x 4]

 #  Year     LD.D     LD.L      LD.P
 #1 1992 118.7717 48.12458 119.70139
 #2 1993 167.8096 19.96206  61.37151
 #3 1994 111.0920 33.75413  93.17205
```

Using `data.table`.  Convert to `data.table` using `setDT` and use `lapply` on a `S`ubset of `D`ata.table (`.SD`) columns and get the `mean`.  Use `by` to specify the grouping variable `Year`.

```
  library(data.table)
  setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=TRUE), by=Year]
  #   Year     LD.D     LD.L      LD.P
  #1: 1992 118.7717 48.12458 119.70139
  #2: 1993 167.8096 19.96206  61.37151
  #3: 1994 111.0920 33.75413  93.17205
```

Or using `base R`.  There are different ways `aggregate`, `by`, `split` etc.  Here is one with `by`.  Use `regex` (lookbehind) to get the `Year`.  In this case, I am getting the `Y` prefix also as it doesn't affect the results.

```
 Year <- gsub("(?<=[0-9])\\..*$", "", row.names(df), perl=TRUE)
 do.call(`rbind`,by(df, Year, FUN= colMeans, na.rm=TRUE))
 #          LD.D     LD.L      LD.P
 #Y.1992 118.7717 48.12458 119.70139
 #Y.1993 167.8096 19.96206  61.37151
 #Y.1994 111.0920 33.75413  93.17205
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(LD.D = c(67.89552605, 227.1370541, 94.5326718, 
 106.8793485, 97.41402289, 150.045093, 106.5888189, 110.7493543, 
 237.1246502, 234.5403261, 94.5326718, 106.8793485, 97.41402289, 
 150.045093, 106.5888189), LD.L = c(33.21192862, 79.67211036, 
 24.72816922, 56.07635245, 46.93434073, 19.64290196, 21.38886866, 
 25.41765759, 16.43006029, 16.93082727, 24.72816922, 56.07635245, 
 46.93434073, 19.64290196, 21.38886866), LD.P = c(90.7750688, 
 154.5165077, 151.665545, 100.6711004, 100.8787496, 27.81953228, 
 84.82532249, 70.02222315, 75.17407065, 49.01639754, 151.665545, 
 100.6711004, 100.8787496, 27.81953228, 84.82532249)), .Names = c("LD.D", 
 "LD.L", "LD.P"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Y.1992.a1", 
 "Y.1992.a2", "Y.1992.a3", "Y.1992.a4", "Y.1992.a5", "Y.1993.a1", 
 "Y.1993.a2", "Y.1993.a3", "Y.1993.a4", "Y.1993.a5", "Y.1994.a1", 
 "Y.1994.a2", "Y.1994.a3", "Y.1994.a4", "Y.1994.a5"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `aggregate` where `DF` is the data frame:

```
aggregate(DF, list(Year = gsub("^Y.|.[^.]*$", "", rownames(DF))), mean)
```